# Enumerating a list of EntityObject items as a list of specific EF objects

Tags: linq, entity-framework, .net-4.0

In my DAL I have a data access object that retrievs database records to an EntityObject List:

```
private List<EntityObject> entities;

var pList = context.Products.Where(...);
entities = new List<EntityObject>(pList);
```

To work with this List in my BI layer I need to enumarate through this `List<EntityObject>` as a list of `Product` objects. I can easily convert back like this:

```
var pList = Data.Entities.Select(p => p as Product);
```

but doesn't this create a copy of the `List<EntityObject>` doubling my memory footprint for this collection which would be a concern with large collections?

If so, is there a way to enumarete through this `List<EntityObject>` as `List<Product>` instead of converting back to `Product` and than enumerating through that copy?

Comment: Could you explain why you're not creating a `List<Product>` instead? It seems like a much simpler solution, and it is not often a problem to accept a `List<T> where T : EntityObject` anywhere you're currently accepting a `List<EntityObject>`.

Comment: Because this "generic" list can hold many different EF objects and this way I get to deal with only one List in my base class instead of having dozens of lists for dozens of different specific EF objects...

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what is the relation between the first `pList` and the second one. And what is `Data.Entities`? Is that the same as `entities`?

Comment: Yes, Data.Entities is a public property using Data.entities as a private backing field in this DAL class used by BI objects... pList is a local variable that is passed into the consctructor of the entities List<EntityObject> list... hope that makes sense...

Comment: @DeanKuga `Select(p => p as Product)` suggested to me that all entities in this specific list would be `Product`s. You've received answers suggesting `OfType<Product>()` for your use; I'm seconding (actually, thirding) it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but doesn't this create a copy of the List doubling my
>   memory footprint for this collection which would be a concern with
>   large collections?

No, this would just make a copy of the *references* to the entities, so that should be of no concern.

Also a safer way to do your cast would be:

```
var pList = Data.Entities.OfType<Product>().ToList();
```

Or you can just directly enumerate through the products:

```
foreach(var product in Data.Entities.OfType<Product>())
{
   //..
}
```

Comment: In his code, he's not calling `ToList()`, so it wouldn't even create copied of the references.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that is the case but wanted to confirm, also OfType<Product> is a better solution so +1 for @svick and you and selecting your reply as answer because of the good suggestion to use OfType instead of as...

Comment: @svick: yes - but OP was talking about lists, so I assumed his intention was to create another list, even though his code example didn't show that

Comment: @DeanKuga: It depends on your use case which is the better one to use -if you have potentially a list that might contain multiple types use `OfType()` but if there always should be only one type use `Cast()` so at least it blows up right away if something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, calling just `Select()` (without following it with `ToList()` or `new List()`) does not create another `List`, so you don't have to worry about memory footprint. What it does is that it computes the sequence of `Products` using the lambda you provided. If the lambda contained some complicated computation and you iterated over the result several times, this could cause performance problems, but that's not the case here.

There are two alternative ways that you could use to express the same cast, but they have some differences what happens when the list contains objects that are not `Product`s:

- `Select(p => p as Product)`: the one you're using right now. If the sequence contains objects that are not `Product`s, they will turn into `null`s.
- `OfType<Product>()`: non-`Products` will be filtered out.
- `Cast<Product>()`: if the sequence contains non-`Product`s, it throws an exception. This is probably the version you want.

Comment: Thanks for additional info, it is very useful but List<EntityObject> cannot contain objects other then Product (and even if it could, I would want them filtered out in this specific case) so Cast<Product> is not really what I want, OfType<Product> is...